# Multiple instances of slidetoggle JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

I have 3 divs that i'm using to show navigation at the top of my page in my site. All using the JQuery function:

```
$('#div_button').click( function() {
        $('#div_nav').slideToggle();
);
```

The problem is, I can get a scenario where I get 2 slidetoggles/ divs on top of one another and thats not good. When I click one button to start slideToggle I would like to remove any other divs that are currently being shown.

A picture describing the problem:

[image: 2 DIVS ON TOP OF EACH OTHER]

Can anyone propose a solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please note that in the image, the divs are different, just a copy and paste, to generate more than one type of div.

Comment: Something like this maybe? http://jsfiddle.net/78TRb/ I work with an `.active` class to check which one is opened.

Comment: @Bondye hey bondye, any chance of getting that code to run with id's instead of classes? Looks like it could work.

Comment: If you use ID (which is unique) you only can have 1 button per page in your website. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/78TRb/1/

Comment: @Bondye Thats what i'm using, one button per page. No need for classes as the buttons are not displayed multiple times.. Only once

Comment: Ok, Sorry for my misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a way to solve this problem. Basically you need to use this function to wait for other slideToggles or slideUPs to complete:

```
$('#tcd-home-view-nav').slideUp(function(){
    // Animation complete.
    $('#tcd-home-edit-nav').slideToggle();
});
```

Cheers people for helping me solve this. Chris

Answer (score 0):

`hide()` all other `div` first

```
$('#div_button').click( function() {
    $('.otherDivClass').hide(); 
   $('#div_nav').slideToggle();
);
```

Comment: its right, but it doesnt give the desired effect. it instantly hides the div, where I would like the currenlty showing div to slide up and after completion the new div to slide down.

Answer (score 0):

Using a plugin like Accordion allows you to apply the functionality you're after without adding classes to your heading and content elements.

http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/

The alternative, if you're convinced that you need to stick with using IDs, is to write 3 separate click functions, opening and closing the relevant elements with each.

Comment: WHY 3? im only slideToggling view and edit + accordion doesnt give me the desired effect, i dont want it too look like a list

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding. It's hard to get your meaning without some code.